# jQuery selecting a selector based on two data attributes

Tags: jquery

I have 2 variables in JS

```
var meeting_id = 3; var guest_id = 44; <tr data-guest-id="44" data-meeting-id="3">
```

how do I that following selector in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [*attribute equals*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
var selector = 'tr[data-meeting-id="'+meeting_id+'"][data-guest-id="'+guest_id+'"]';

$(selector).foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [jQuery Multiple Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/). You would replace the numbers here with variables.

```
$('tr[data-guest-id="44"][data-meeting-id="3"]')
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfhmpepd/) *I used an input so I could demonstrate how it worked.